# Does Android encourage reusing their Menu-Icons? Where to get them all?

Tags: android, icons, drawable

They do not write anything about licenses at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#menuapx (Menu Icons)

I guess they want to have standard icons look the same in all apps, so users dont get confused. Right?

Now I would love to use the Menu-Icon "see map" (a folded map) from the Google Places App. Where can I get it for a commercial project? (Its not in [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/res/res/drawable-hdpi;h=6e54b40a4b136aaa68016fd6ea1da16d9a9f8724;hb=HEAD))

Comment: Which Options-Menu-Icons from google are open source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Places is a proprietary app by Google, just like Gmail, Maps, or Voice.  These apps are not open-source, so you won't be able to go and find their icons in the git hub.

BAD IDEA:
You could always take a screen shot of the app using DDMS and create your own icon from that, but you might be running some legal risks (since the app isn't open-source).  It'd be like using the Photoshop icon for your app.

Comment: I meant the option menu icon "see map" from Places. Not the Places Icon itself.

Comment: I know you weren't talking about the app's icon.  I'm explaining that the reason you can't find the options menu graphic in git hub is because the app is not open-source.  The apps under `platform/packages/apps` at http://android.git.kernel.org/ are the open-source ones.

Comment: Also, looking at that guidelines link you edited in above, there's another nice 'map mode' icon that may work just as well.

Comment: Yeah I'm already using this one, but the other icon is even more fancy ;)